# Django Queryset - Get counts by model.choices

Tags: django, django-models, count, django-queryset

I have below model, which has all the details about customer `Leads`. Customer wants to see his `Leads` followup statuses.

```
class FollowUp(models.Model):
    CALL_CHOICES = [("0", "Call Unanswered"),
                  ("1", "Call Later"),
                  ("2", "Visit Scheduled"),
                  ("3", "Not Visited"),
                  ("4", "Not reachable"),
                  ("5", "Wrong Number"),
                  ("6", "Not Interested"),
                  ("7", "Deal Closed")]
    status = models.CharField(_("Call Status"),
            max_length = 20,
            choices = CALL_CHOICES,
            default = '1'
        )
    next_action_on = DateTimeField(_("Next Action"), auto_now_add=False, 
                null=True, blank=True)
    reminder = models.BooleanField(_("reminder"), default=False)  
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Lead(models.Model):
    followups = models.ManyToManyField(FollowUp, verbose_name=_("Follow up"), blank=True)
    ...
```

How can I get `Lead` counts of each `status` choice. such as

```
{
 'Call Unanswered': 12 #Leads, 
 'Call Later': 10 # Leads  
 'Visit Scheduled': 20, #Leads, 
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
Lead.objects.aggregate(
    **{
        choice[1]: Count(
            'followups', filter=Q(followups__status=choice[0])
        ) for choice in Followup.CALL_CHOICES
    }
)
```

This would return something like:

```
{'Call Unanswered': 0,
 'Call Later': 0,
 'Visit Scheduled': 0,
 'Not Visited': 0,
 'Not reachable': 0,
 'Wrong Number': 0,
 'Not Interested': 0,
 'Deal Closed': 0}
```

Comment: Really interesting solution, I was trying to figure out one solution like this...

Comment: One hit to the database :)

Comment: Least DB hit always a priority :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the for iterator to iterate through CALL_CHOICES and filter the rows based on the status.

```
queryset = Leads.objects.all()
res = {}
for i in FollowUp.CALL_CHOICES:
    res[i[1]] = queryset.filter(followups__status=i[0]).aggregate(total=Count('pk'))['total']
print(res)
```

At the end of the script you will get each pair of values.

Answer (score 1):

You would get the count like this:

```
>>> Leads.objects.filter(follow_up__status=0).count()
>>> 10
```